# iphone avTouch sample code - simulator not showing the audio meter levels

Tags: iphone, audio, sdk, ios-4.2

I recently got started with iphone programming and was checking out the avTouch sample project from Apple in the iphone simulator, but the audio levels are not showing in the simulator (haven't checked with a device). The audio plays, and I can change the volume, but the audio meter which is supposed to be there don't show up. I have latest version of the Xcode(3.2.5) and latest iOS (4.2) installed. Does anyone know why this could be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is because `OpenGL ES` isn't available on the Mac. This is why the simulator is really pointless. About all it's good for is UI testing.

Short answer: It'll work fine on the device.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at this too.  There's a "_useGL" flag in the initWithCoder method.  Set that to "NO" and it'll display fine on the simulator.